# How to determine file name or .DISPLAY_NAME for PickVisualMedia() uri?

Tags: android

Using `registerForActivityResult(  new PickVisualMedia(), .....` one obtains uris like `content://media/picker/0/com.android.providers.media.photopicker/media/1000000037`

Trying to determine the file name (.DISPLAY_NAME) delivers `1000000037.jpg`.

```
DocumentFile docFile = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, uri));
docFile.getName() //delivers 1000000037.jpg
```

or with:

```
String projection[] = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

String displayName = cursor.getString(0); //delivers 1000000037.jpg
```

The actual filename is `IMG_20230816_070923.jpg`.

Using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` the uri for the same file is like
`content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1000000037`
From this uri one can determine the right file name with both methods.

So why is this media provider giving a fantasy file name instead of the actual one? Or how to determine the file name?